# how to stream live content from YouTube using QWebEngineView

Tags: c++, qt, youtube, h.264, qwebengineview

I'm trying to stream live content from youtube using QWebEngineView's load method.
I'm currently passing the live media's url as an argument to load(), as follows:

```
QWebEngineView *webEngineView = new QWebEngineView;
webEngineView->load(QUrl("https://someURL"));
```

I get a blank screen with the following piece of text
"Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available". Live streams worked before, but it suddently stop working. I already have Flash Player installed.

And Btw, I really would love in addition to getting live content displayed through the QWebEngineView.

I'm using Qt 5.9.3 MSVC2017, on a windows 10 machine

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?